# Official documentation of synclient parameters

Tags: touchpad

Where is the official documentation of the parameters supported by `synclient` tool to twek touchpads?

There are a lot of matches if you search the web for "HorizHysteresis" or "TouchpadOff". But I could not find the official reference.

Comment: @Rinzwind sorry, I am blind. Your link does not tell me the meaning of `"TouchpadOff=2" .

Comment: Your questions became intruiging. The documentation only mentions 0 and 1 (on and off). 2 seems to indicate "only disable scrolling and tapping" BUT it is no where in any reference I looked at.

Comment: I wrote an answer myself. There is a link to the docs for `"TouchpadOff=2"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found it:

http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html

Thanks to @Rinzwind for the link to synclient man page.

Answer (score 3):

[Manual page](http://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/synclient.1.html) from x.org. So that might be the official documentation though it is a manual styled one so it will be the same information if you type `man synclient`.

The arch website has a very thorough documentation: [Touchpad_Synaptics](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Touchpad_Synaptics)

And the command itself will list all user options with:

```
synclient -l
```

---

Regarding: "TouchpadOff=2" in comments: The arch website has a section "Software toggle" that seems to indicate it has a 0 and 1 as options; not a 2.

---

edit: I also found this [script](https://forums.opensuse.org/showthread.php/428075-Laptop-Touchpad-clicking):

```
#!/bin/bash
# touchpad-off - bash script to turn the synaptics touch pad off

# synclient TouchpadOff=1
# Alternatively, only disable scrolling and tapping
synclient TouchpadOff=2
```

But I have not found any official reference on this...

So it seems your question is not that odd ;)

Comment: The arch website is not the official documentation.

Comment: Why care if it is official? I'd rather have good documentation ;)

Comment: If upstream does not deliver good docs, there will be hunderts blog posts which don't get updated. My point of view: If there is no official (from upstream) docs, there are no good docs.